# A question about Caratheodory's Theorem of Convex Sets

Tags: convex-analysis

As I understand it, Caratheodory's Theorem of Convex sets essentially states

If $Q$ is a set in a vector space of dimension $n$ and **x** lies in the convex hull of $Q$, then **x** can be written as a convex combination of no more than $n+1$ points in $Q$.

Is this a biconditional statement? I.e. if **x** can be written as a convex combination of no more than $n+1$ points in $Q$, then is **x** required to lie in the the convex hull of $Q$?

Any sources and examples/counter-examples would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the _definition_ of the convex hull of $Q$?

Comment: Ahhh. The convex hull of $Q$ can be defined as the set of all convex combinations of points in $Q$, so if **x** can be written as a convex combination of points in $Q$, then **x** must lie in $Q$, correct?

Comment: yes${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

The convex hull of $Q$ is the smallest convex set of $\mathbb R^n$ that contains every point in $Q$.  It is the intersection of all convex sets that contain every point of $Q$.  So what is a "convex" set?  By one often seen definition, it is a set closed under drawing line segments.  A set is convex precisely if, for any two points $A$ and $B$ in the set, every point on the segment from $A$ to $B$ is in the set.

"Convex combination" is often defined as a linear combination in which the sum of the coefficients is $1$ and every coefficient is non-negative.

It's easy to see that the line segment consists of the convex combination of *two* points.  The problem now is: what if there are more than two?  Could one get a bigger set by closing under convex combinations of more than two points?  I think as long as that number of points is finite, one can prove simply by induction on the number of points that one doesn't get any more.